# "No cells found" error

Tags: vba, excel

I have this piece of code getting a "No Cells Found" error. I don't understand why if I am using `on error resume next` and there will be times there won't be any `"INATIVE"` in that column.

```
Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
```

where `12` can also be written as `xlCellTypeVisible`.

Here are the lines before and after for more clarity:

```
With Sheets("Temp Activos")
    On Error Resume Next
    .UsedRange.AutoFilter 6, "INATIVE"
    On Error GoTo 0
    Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete 
    r = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A"))
    .UsedRange.AutoFilter
```

Comment: The `On Error GoTo 0` clears the `On Error Resume Next` condition.  So you'll need to move the `On Error GoTo 0` down until just before the `End With`

Answer (score 0):

Converting comment to answer:

The `On Error GoTo 0` clears the `On Error Resume Next` condition. So you'll need to move the `On Error GoTo 0` down until just before the `End With`.